# Using providers in Java AES encryption

Tags: java, encryption, cryptography, bouncycastle

This may be a noobie question but I'm confused on how providers work. I've tried reading this https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/security/overview/jsoverview.html but it doesn't quite make sense to me. Say we have:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding", "BC")
```

and

```
Cipher cipher= Cipher.getInstance("AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding")
```

According to the link it sounds like the provider indicates the implementation that is in use but isn't AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding basically the same independent of the provider? In the example does bouncy castle (what I'm guessing "BC" corresponds to) happen to have a more efficient algorithm than the default implementation? Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> isn't AES/CBC/PKCS5Padding basically the same independent of the
>   provider?

Yes, it is.

> In the example does bouncy castle (what I'm guessing "BC" corresponds
>   to) happen to have a more efficient algorithm than the default
>   implementation?

Probably not. In the case of AES in particular, recent Oracle providers are likely to be dramatically faster than Bouncycastle due to their use of native AES hardware when available.

> So why specify the provider?

Ok, I know you didn't ask that but that seemed to be where you were headed. In most cases you should *not* specify a provider. The general rule is to avoid specifying a provider unless you have a good reason to do so. Leaving the provider unspecified increases portability.

Unfortunately, there are some cases I've encountered where you probably need to specify the provider. The abstractions provided in the JCE just do not cover all the situations that arise in practice. If you run into one of those it's best to ask a separate question.

Comment: @justan0therlurker  just extending he answer - some providers may have algorithm or parameters which are not available in JRE by default (e. g. AES-CGM or RSA-OAEP has been added only in recent years, functions as Keccak, etc )

Comment: @gusto2  Thanks for your input. Follow up question: is there any difference from specifying the "BC" provider and using the JCE API than in using the BC API (ex: https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/166997/bouncy-castle-128bit-aes-cbc-pkcs7-in-java)?

Comment: @justan0therlurker functionally it is the same (the SPI should return the same implementation), still I'd advice you to use the default Crypto API rather than nail yourself to a specific implementation or version